# Haskell: Defining a variable inside a typeclass

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I stumbled upon this problem while playing around with classes.
So basically instead of defining functions inside a class, I want to define variables. In my case I'm defining a variable `maxvalue` inside the class `Maxable`. This worked just fine with `Int`. Now assuming a type `a` is an instance of `Maxable`, I want to define `instance Maxable (Maybe a)`, which you can see in the third block of my code didn't work.

```haskell
class Maxable a where
  maxvalue :: a

-- This works fine
instance Maxable Int where
  maxvalue = 2147483647

-- Error: Could not deduce (Maxable a1) arising from a use of ‘maxvalue’
instance Maxable a => Maxable (Maybe a) where
  maxvalue = maxvalue :: a
```

What should I replace `maxvalue = maxvalue :: a` with so that *"(Maybe a).maxvalue == a.maxvalue"* ?

Comment: (See also the [`Bounded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) typeclass)

Comment: It helps to write [`InstanceSigs`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html?highlight=instancesigs#extension-InstanceSigs). The `Int` instance has type signature `maxvalue :: Int`. The `Maybe a` instance has signature `maxvalue :: Maybe a`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're actually really close to the right answer!

First, to actually solve the problem, you need to recognize that in your `Maxable` instance for `Maybe a`, the type of `maxvalue` needs to be of type `Maybe a`.  However, in your definition, you're making it of type `a`.  So, how do you turn a value of type `a` into a value of type `Maybe a`?  You use the `Just` constructor.  In short, you can write:

```hs
instance Maxable a => Maxable (Maybe a) where
  maxvalue = Just maxvalue
```

As it turns out, GHC is smart enough to use the right `maxvalue` without you even needing to use the `:: a` annotation.

---

But, what about that error you got?  Why did it tell you something about `Maxable a1`?  The problem that GHC is pointing out comes from the fact that you used the explicit type signature `maxvalue :: a` in your definition.  By default, GHC does not scope type variables, so GHC didn't know that you wanted to use the same `a` there that you're using in your instance head.  GHC *assumed* you just wanted a new, fresh type variable, which, internally, it decided to call `a1`.  Then, it got confused at you because, while it knows that `a` is `Maxable` (because you said so in the instance context), it doesn't know that `a1` is `Maxable`.

To get a better error message in this case, you can enable the GHC extension `ScopedTypeVariables` by adding

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

to the top of your file.  If you run your current code with this language extension, you'll get a different error, with GHC complaining that `a` is not equal to `Maybe a`.  As I stated above, this can be solved by using the `Just` constructor.